# Flutter Blue Plus is not receiving data from a connected ESP

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

I am trying to send a string back to the Flutter app to confirm that the ESP received the request. Using the Arduino IDE serial monitor, I can confirm that the ESP is receiving the requests. However, the Flutter app is not receiving data from the esp. Nothing gets printed in the listener. I omitted some code from the BLE service such as the init method and the dispose method as I do not believe it has anything to do with the issue.
Here is my Flutter code:

```dart
class BleService {

  static const String kServiceUUid = '6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E';
  static const String kChannelUUid = '6E400002-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E';
  static const String kNoteUUid = '6E400004-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E';
  static const String kNotifierUUid = '6E400003-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E';

  static ValueNotifier<Set<BluetoothDevice>> seenDevices = ValueNotifier({});
  static ValueNotifier<Set<BleDevice>> scannedDevices = ValueNotifier({});
  static BluetoothDevice? connectedDevice;
  static String? connectedDeviceWin;
  static StreamSubscription? sub;
  static StreamSubscription? connectionStateSub;

  // StreamController for incoming BLE data
  static StreamController<String> incomingDataController =
      StreamController<String>.broadcast();

  // Getter for the stream
  static Stream<String> get incomingDataStream => incomingDataController.stream;

  static void scanDevices() async {
    
      if (!isBlueToothOn.value) {
        if (Platform.isAndroid) {
          await FlutterBluePlus.turnOn();
        }
        if (!isBlueToothOn.value) {
          ToastService.show('Please start bluetooth to continue!');
          return;
        }
      
      sub = FlutterBluePlus.scanResults.listen(
        (results) {
          seenDevices.value = {
            ...seenDevices.value,
            ...results
                .map((e) => e.device)
                .where((element) => element.advName.trim().isNotEmpty)
          };
        },
      );
    }

    
      await FlutterBluePlus.startScan(
        timeout: const Duration(minutes: 2),
        removeIfGone: const Duration(seconds: 10),
        continuousUpdates: true,
      );
    
    stopScanTimer = Timer(const Duration(minutes: 2), () => stopScan());
  }

  
  static Future<void> connect(
      {BluetoothDevice? device, String? deviceId}) async {
    if (device != null) {
      // Connect to the BLE device
      await device.connect();
      connectedDevice = FlutterBluePlus.connectedDevices.firstOrNull;

      // Discover services
      final List<BluetoothService> services =
          await connectedDevice!.discoverServices();
      for (final service in services) {
        if (service.uuid == Guid(kServiceUUid)) {
          for (final characteristic in service.characteristics) {
            // Check if this is the characteristic we're interested in
            if (characteristic.uuid == Guid(kNotifierUUid)) {
              // Subscribe to notifications
              await characteristic.setNotifyValue(true);
              print('setNotifyValue');
              // Handle incoming notifications
              characteristic.lastValueStream.listen((value) {
                // Add incoming data to the stream
                final String receivedData = String.fromCharCodes(value);
                print(receivedData);
                incomingDataController.add(receivedData);
              });
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  static Future<void> sendChangeChannel(int channel) async {
    if (channel > 0 && channel <= 16) {
      await sendData(channel.toString(), characteristicUUid: kChannelUUid);
    }
  }

  static Future<void> sendChangeNote(int note) async {
    if (note >= 0 && note <= 127) {
      await sendData(note.toString(), characteristicUUid: kNoteUUid);
    }
  }

  static Future<void> sendData(String data,
      {required String characteristicUUid,
      String serviceUUid = kServiceUUid}) async {
    if (!isConnected) return;
    if (Platform.isWindows && connectedDeviceWin != null) {
      for (final c in await WinBle.discoverCharacteristics(
          address: connectedDeviceWin!, serviceId: serviceUUid)) {
        if (c.properties.write ?? false) {
          await WinBle.write(
              address: connectedDeviceWin!,
              service: serviceUUid,
              characteristic: characteristicUUid,
              data: Uint8List.fromList(data.codeUnits),
              writeWithResponse: false);
        }
      }
    } else if (connectedDevice != null) {
      for (final service in await connectedDevice!.discoverServices()) {
        if (service.serviceUuid == Guid(serviceUUid)) {
          for (final c in service.characteristics) {
            if (c.uuid == Guid(characteristicUUid) && c.properties.write) {
              await c.write(data.codeUnits);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

And here is my esp code:

```cpp
#include <BLEDevice.h>
#include <BLEServer.h>
#include <BLEUtils.h>
#include <BLE2902.h>

#define RXD2 5 // Dev board uses Arduino ESP32 Nano Pin D2 as MIDI Out
#define TXD2 2 // Dev board uses Arduino ESP32 Nano Pin D2 as MIDI Out

BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic;
bool deviceConnected = false;

BLECharacteristic *pControlCharacteristic;

int midi_channel = 1;
int midi_note = 40;

#define SERVICE_UUID           "6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E"
#define UUID_MIDI_CHANNEL "6E400002-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E"
#define CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_TX "6E400003-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E"
#define UUID_MIDI_NOTE "6E400004-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E"

class MyServerCallbacks: public BLEServerCallbacks {
  void onConnect(BLEServer* pServer) {
    deviceConnected = true;
  };

  void onDisconnect(BLEServer* pServer) {
    deviceConnected = false;
  }
};

class MyCallbacks: public BLECharacteristicCallbacks {
  void onWrite(BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic) {
    std::string rxValue_stdstr = pCharacteristic->getValue();
    String rxValue_string = String(rxValue_stdstr.c_str());
    int rx_channel = rxValue_string.toInt();

    Serial.print("Adjust MIDI Channel to "); Serial.println(rx_channel);

    if (rx_channel >= 1 && rx_channel <= 16) {
      midi_channel = rx_channel;
      sendMidiChannelNotification();
    }

    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("=====END=RECEIVE=====");
    Serial.println();
  }

  void sendMidiChannelNotification() {
    if (deviceConnected) {
      String response = "MIDI Channel Set to: " + String(midi_channel);
      pCharacteristic->setValue(response.c_str());
      pCharacteristic->notify();
    }
  }
};

class MyControlCallbacks: public BLECharacteristicCallbacks {
  void onWrite(BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic) {
    std::string controlValue_stdstr = pCharacteristic->getValue();
    String controlValue_string = String(controlValue_stdstr.c_str());
    int rx_note = controlValue_string.toInt();

    Serial.print("Adjust MIDI Note to "); Serial.println(rx_note);

    if (rx_note >= 0 && rx_note <= 127) {
      midi_note = rx_note;
      sendMidiNoteNotification();
    }

    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("=====END=RECEIVE=====");
    Serial.println();
  }

  void sendMidiNoteNotification() {
    if (deviceConnected) {
      String response = "MIDI Note Set to: " + String(midi_note);
      pControlCharacteristic->setValue(response.c_str());
      pControlCharacteristic->notify();
    }
  }
};

void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial2.begin(31250, SERIAL_8N1, RXD2, TXD2);

  BLEDevice::init("E-Drum Brain");
  BLEServer *pServer = BLEDevice::createServer();
  pServer->setCallbacks(new MyServerCallbacks());

  BLEService *pService = pServer->createService(SERVICE_UUID);

  pCharacteristic = pService->createCharacteristic(
    UUID_MIDI_CHANNEL,
    BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE | BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_NOTIFY
  );
  pCharacteristic->addDescriptor(new BLE2902());
  pCharacteristic->setCallbacks(new MyCallbacks());

  pControlCharacteristic = pService->createCharacteristic(
    UUID_MIDI_NOTE,
    BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE | BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_NOTIFY
  );
  pControlCharacteristic->setCallbacks(new MyControlCallbacks());

  pService->start();
  pServer->getAdvertising()->start();

  Serial.println("Waiting for a client connection to notify...");
}

void loop(void) {
  delay(1000);
  sendNoteOn(midi_channel, midi_note, 127);
  delay(10);
  sendNoteOff(midi_channel, midi_note);
}

void sendNoteOn(byte channel, byte note, byte velocity) {
  Serial2.write(0x90 | (channel - 1));
  Serial2.write(note);
  Serial2.write(velocity);
}

void sendNoteOff(byte channel, byte note) {
  Serial2.write(0x80 | (channel - 1));
  Serial2.write(note);
  Serial2.write(0);
}
```